# PhaseScriptExecution failed for react-native-config on Xcode build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-config

I am trying to build my React Native project on Xcode and it is failing. The build target is react-native-config with the error: Run custom shell script '[CP-User] Config codegen' "**Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**".

Trying to run it with --verbose, I get the following:

> The following build commands failed: PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Config\ codegen /User/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-config-build/Script-21BEEA33BD6A21BF27B73D38DC1AD4.sh

I am running React Native 0.63.1 with React-Native-Config 1.4.1 and I have tried reinstalling node_modules, pods, deleting DerivedData and cleaning the build but no luck. I also do not see any references to react-native-config under Build Phases > Run Script.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually, this is caused by a badly formatted `.env` file. Double-check your `.env`.

Comment: I had a comment in my `.env` file (`# with three words`) and when I removed it, I got past this error ‍♂️

Comment: where is this .env file located?

Comment: At the root of your project.

Comment: there is no env file in my project. :/

Comment: @SRBBans you need to create one, usually `.env` are added to `.gitignore`. Can you verify if there's `.env` in your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: I have created a new Project...So, does it require an env file to run the initial demo project?

Comment: Are you experiencing the same error message? `PhaseScriptExecution failed for react-native-config on XCode build`?

Comment: For some reason, I switched a comment from `# the comment` to `; the comment` some time ago but switching it back to a # fixed it!

Comment: narrowed down the causes I found it might really because of the bad format. I encode .env to base64 then later decode it to .env file, then the build failed. Anyone faced this ?

Comment: I had a space at the beginning of a line. Guh. I spent all day on this!

Answer (score 5):

Usually this problem when a dependency is not updated.

You can try the following steps:

```
1-) cd ios
2-) rm -rf Podfile.lock
3-) rm -rf Pods
4-) delete .xcworkspace
5-) pod install
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me. :-/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same Problem, I followed a tutorial to build ios, it is pretty old (one year) in tutorial I added code which include some thing like

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  if target.name == 'React'
  target.remove_from_project
  end
  if target.name == 'react-native-config'
    phase = target.project.new(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXShellScriptBuildPhase)
    phase.shell_script = 'cd ../../'\
    '&& RNC_ROOT=./node_modules/react-native-config/'\
    '&& export SYMROOT=$RNC_ROOT/ios/ReactNativeConfig'\
    '&& export BUILD_DIR=$RNC_ROOT/ios/ReactNativeConfig'\
    '&& ruby $RNC_ROOT/ios/ReactNativeConfig/BuildDotenvConfig.ruby'
    target.build_phases << phase
    target.build_phases.move(phase,0)
  end
 end
end
```

please delete it from podfile and follow the doc of react-native-config to use environment variables [here](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#availability-in-build-settings-and-infoplist)
after delete dont forget pod install

while building take care of build scheme (which one are you using while build time)

Comment: I didn't have this code in my Podfile but following these instructions which you have linked to fixed the issue: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#availability-in-build-settings-and-infoplist

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is facing this issue while using rbenv, please ensure that ruby is installed locally in project folder.

Comment: this helped me thx. i did  rbenv install

Answer (score 0):

Occur due to some mismatch of packages, search for a package which shows the error and remove the package

After that

delete ios folder
install react native eject package

```
npm i react-native-eject
```

re-create ios folder

```
npx react-native eject
```

install pod

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I used `ts-node` to run some typescript code in the Run Script phase, the ts-node executable was not in `/usr/local/bin/ts-node` which caused the build to fail.

Try to run the code inside the Run Script editor directly in the terminal, that might give you a clue about why the build fails.